# Elseif condition won't work

Tags: php, if-statement

With "elseif" i want to check if there are more than 4 elements and than give all the elements the class of "col-md-5ones" but nothing happens.

```
if(sizeof($elements)>0) {
    $size = ceil(12 / sizeof($elements));
    foreach($elements AS $element) {
         echo '<article class="col-md-'.$size.'">'.$element.'</article>';
    }
} 

elseif(sizeof($elements)==5) {
    foreach($elements AS $element) {
        echo '<article class="col-md-5ones">'.$element.'</article>';
    }
}
```

This shows me the correct count of elements:

```
echo sizeof($elements);
```

So i don't understand why i can't do a elseif condition here?

Comment: Have you tried to change `elseif(sizeof($elements)==5)` by `elseif(sizeof($elements) > 4)`.

You ask to add a class if you have more than 4 items, but your condition only checked if you add 5.

Also, you first condition check if `$elements` is bigger then 0. You will never enter in the else if you have more than 1 element. 

I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first condition check if $elements is bigger than 0.

In that logic, if $elements value is 4, you will still go in the first if() condition.

```
if(sizeof($elements) > 0 && sizeof($elements) <= 4) {
    $size = ceil(12 / sizeof($elements));
    foreach($elements AS $element) {
         echo '<article class="col-md-'.$size.'">'.$element.'</article>';
    }
} 

elseif(sizeof($elements) > 4) {
    foreach($elements AS $element) {
        echo '<article class="col-md-5ones">'.$element.'</article>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second condition is evaluated to TRUE only when the first one is TRUE. Which means that the else part is never executed.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because of a conflict between the two conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
if(sizeof($elements)>0) {
    $size = ceil(12 / sizeof($elements));

    if(sizeof($elements) > 4) {
        foreach($elements AS $element) {
            echo '<article class="col-md-5ones">'.$element.'</article>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code-only solution is incorrect. It only outputs if the size is 5.

Comment: This still skips the `'col-md-' . $size` case.